# jquery dynamically created checkbox not working properly with function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a jquery for dynamic generation of check box as well as subtraction operation performed on text box with the value of checked check box. Jquery is working fine with predefined checkbox but not working with dynamically created checkbox. I tried solution like "ON" delegate but still i am struck here my code is like

**HTML**

```
<select class="select valid" id="destination" name="destination">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="92">92(11)</option>
    <option value="923">923(12)</option>
    <option value="9230">9230(12)</option>
    <option value="9231">9231(12)</option>
    <option value="9232">9232(12)</option>
    <option value="9233">9233(12)</option>
    <option value="9234">9234(12)</option>
    <option value="9235">925(12)</option>
</select>
<label for="port">Ports</label>
<input type="text" id="port" max="128" min="1"/><br><br />
<input type='checkbox' value="5" name='ch1[]' class='checkbox'/>Working Fine
<input type="submit" onsubmit="" value="Save" id="button1" name="button1">
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#destination').change(function(){
        $( ".dev" ).remove();
        $( "#button1" ).before("<div class='dev' style='float:left;width:280px;'>

            <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='ch1[]' class='checkbox'/>Not Working</div>");
    }); 
    var $cbs = $('.checkbox');
    function calcUsage(){
        var total = 0; //$("#more").val();
        $cbs.each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            {
                // total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(this).val());
                total = parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $("#port").val($("#port").val()-total);
        if($("#port").val()<0)
        {
            alert("Check Your Port Capacity");
        }
    }
    //For  checkboxes
    $cbs.click(function() {
        calcUsage();
    });
});
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nt5ymn23/1/)

(*this is a sample code but i am populating checkbox on AJAX call for selected destination)

Comment: There are a lot of same questions, but let's repeat once more: for dynamically created elements you should use delegated event handler. For example, `$(document).on('click', '.checkbox', function() {`

Comment: @Regent I checked all solution and done some hit  & try but I posted it here because i am unable to diagnose whats is wrong. and i mentioned about delegates above. Thank You.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, I haven't read your question text entirely, so have missed sentence about delegated events. Nevertheless, the example is here. By the way, it will be better to add `.on()` to more specific static parent rather than to `document`.

Comment: @Regent i followed you suggestion but with the mixture of  suggestion below. I  solved it. Thanx for ur suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

your not binding the new checkboxes that you are adding.

The click event is just binded to the checkboxs that you have when the document is ready. Your new checkboxes are not part of $cbs.

Comment: +1 thanx you suggestion helped me a lot but with the use of "on" delegated event as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#destination').change(function(){
    $( ".dev" ).remove();
    $( "#button1" ).before("<div class='dev' style='float:left;width:280px;'>

        <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='ch1[]' class='checkbox'/>Not Working</div>");
}); 
function calcUsage(){
    var total = 0; //$("#more").val();
     $('.checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            // total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat($(this).val());
            total = parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $("#port").val($("#port").val()-total);
    if($("#port").val()<0)
    {
        alert("Check Your Port Capacity");
    }
}
//For  checkboxes
$(document).on('click', '.checkbox', function()  {
    calcUsage();
});
```

});